# NHIbernate IHttpModule and TransactionScope

Tags: wcf, nhibernate, msmq, transactionscope

Just wondering what other's thoughts are on using a TransactionScope in an IHttpModule.
For example:

```
BeginRequest
//start new TransactionScope
// start UOW
// Begin UOW transaction

// do some stuff...


EndRequest:
// commit UOW
// commit transaction scope
```

Is it really a wise idea to hold the transactionscope open for the life of a http request? 
I need to write to transactional MSMQ at the same time and have the need for the TransactionScope.  I'd like db updates to be persisted as well as MSMQ messages to be sent, or else, roll it all back...

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would fail randomly because in ASP.NET there is no guarantee that BeginRequest and EndRequest will occur on the same thread (aka [thread-agility](http://tao.qshine.com/note/ThreadIssue.html)). A Transaction scope will throw an exception if you try to dispose of it on a different thread than the one where it was created. So in the occasional event that EndRequest executed on a different thread then BeginRequest, this exception was thrown.

For more detail:

http://www.mattwrock.com/post/2010/12/26/Getting-TransactionScope-to-play-nice-with-NHibernate.aspx

Comment: I found this out several hours after posting.  My other issue was a ISession.Close that caused an issue with the TransactionScope.  Removed the Close() and all worked well.  It was actually the same blog that led me to the Begin/End Request issue you mention. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: No worries, happy to help!  I've been stung by the old _thread agility + log4net_ combo many a time before.

Comment: Somebody has an example of how to use this solution?  The NhOuterTransactionScope is stored in the httpContetx like the session?